# Convertir un string a un integer array

Tags: c++

Tengo un archivo de texto con el siguiente contenido:

```
a 4 a 3 a 7 b c e
```

Los valores los tengo que introducir en un vector y las letras las voy a usar para realizar diferentes operaciones, así que la única solución que se me ocurrió fue dividir este string en dos strings (uno de letras y otro de números) y convertir el string de letras a un array de tipo char y los números a un integer array, sin embargo, cuando trato de convertir el string de números a array de tipo entero no guarda los valores originales y me devuelve los números en código ascii.

Este es mi código:

```
    int main () {
    ifstream archivo("operaciones.txt");
    string line, letras, num;

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "Nombre de archivo incorrecto";
        exit(1);
    }

    char *contenido;
    int *numeros;

    if (archivo.is_open()) {   
            getline(archivo, line);

            for (int i = 0; i < line.size() + 1; i++) {
                if (isdigit(line[i])) {
                    num.push_back(line[i]);
                } else if ((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'e')) {
                    letras.push_back(line[i]);
                }
            }

            contenido = new char[letras.size() + 1];
            strcpy(contenido, letras.c_str());

            numeros = new int[num.size() + 1];
            std :: copy(num.begin(), num.end(), numeros);
            

            for (int j = 0; j < num.size()+1; ++j) {
                cout<<numeros[j];
            }

            letras = ' ';
            num = ' ';
            delete contenido;
            delete numeros;
        
    }
    archivo.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Esta es mi salida:

```
525155
```

Esta operación necesito realizarla varias veces, es por eso que uso pointers para almacenar los valores.
Hay alguna otra forma de leer los datos del archivo y separarlos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás leyendo el contenido del archivo como texto, así que cuando lees un siete en lugar de leer el valor entero `7`, lees el carácter *7*. [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) permite esto porque los caracteres son tipos numéricos y como tales pueden convertirse a números implícitamente.

Tu problema tiene las siguientes soluciones:

1. Convierte el carácter a número antes de guardar:

   ```
   if (isdigit(line[i])) {
       num.push_back(line[i] - '0');
   //                        ^^^^^ <-- Resta el carácter cero al carácter actual.
   } else if ((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'e')) {
       letras.push_back(line[i]);
   }
   ```

   El carácter cero tiene un valor numérico de 30<sub>16</sub> por lo que si lo restas del carácter siete cuyo valor numérico es 37<sub>16</sub> obtienes el valor `7`.

   [image]

   Ten en cuenta que la cadena `num` no será imprimible ya que ninguno de los caracteres del cero al nueve lo son.
2. Intenta leer un número, si la lectura falla intenta leer una letra:

   ```
   int numero;
   char letra;
   std::vector<int> num;
   std::vector<char> letras;

   while (archivo)
   {
       if (archivo >> numero)
           num.push_back(numero);
       else if (archivo.clear(), archivo >> letra)
           letras.push_back(letra);
       else
           break;
   }
   ```

Personalmente prefiero la segunda opción, con la segunda opción y siguiendo las prácticas de C++ moderno, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
std::vector<int> numeros;
std::vector<char> letras;

if (std::ifstream archivo{"operaciones.txt"})
{

    int numero;
    char letra;

    while (archivo)
    {
        if (archivo >> numero)
            numeros.push_back(numero);
        else if (archivo.clear(), archivo >> letra)
            letras.push_back(letra);
        else
            break;
    }
}

std::cout << numeros.size() << " numeros leidos:\n";
for (const auto &numero : numeros)
    std::cout << '\t' << numero << '\n';
std::cout << letras.size() << " letras leidas:\n";
for (const auto &letra : letras)
    std::cout << '\t' << letra << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJra8IwFP2c/IpLB7PCJo7NPVrpLxFGTG9tsCaSpG5M/O3upml9bAjNl3PuPY@kcrt9lI3Qq@PxTmnZtCXCXBnnLYpNwc9Y9R/aofTGFpzvjCqhFN64dMz3nKkKUufLLDP9Fph9YrZohVRGo5v4b58cxpwxA/M5sETACwh4pvMGS5CAC50Qy5IlzAgI5DvBJVQDIeGVgBkRHwQjrAaiJImSSAFTgiuoBwJJAokU8ETwChQROT9wrrSHjVA6Zu9r5JyzrkIsOaehAnS7QWtcfk3JWtgCGvRWuLB2aq@G9sLKWu1u3MGeVljIENVJnAXFKBj02FetGoS0VwnXtg@Ngk@PQTGECyxjfdDJtnX151LIddqzQZ1h4xAutieyQWHT8QNcyHX2US1WuxCL3EmrG1pS03WADpy@/oakaX144SGPUz@YjgOSDBgZqdK4rHsNVhkLqTTaeRCtN3AfpyAbxkOiK@nRwo/OFhHRo/xPgL7CpX@EOntx074bIvc4fNM8jp28ObPoW6thSj/Y8fgL)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Si me funciono. Y tengo otra duda, si por ejemplo tuviera un numero de dos dígitos como lo checaria en un if?

Comment: Con la segunda solución, si un número es de dos o más cifras, no cumplirá la condición `numero < 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba este codigo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (void)
{
    std::vector<int> numeros;
    numeros.push_back('a');
    numeros.push_back('b');
    numeros.push_back('c');
    numeros.push_back('d');
    
    for (int i : numeros) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Y veras que cada `char` tiene su representación en los `int`. Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es pasar de el valor numerico del `char`, no a su valor, sino a su representacion en los`int`. Podemos ver los valores en la tabla y nos damos cuenta que podemos pasarlos de esta manera:

```cpp
entero = caracter - '0';
```

Ahora prueba este codigo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (void)
{
    std::vector<int> numeros;
    numeros.push_back('1' - '0');
    numeros.push_back('4' - '0');
    numeros.push_back('5' - '0');
    numeros.push_back('d' - '0');
    
    for (int i : numeros) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Y veras que los digitos pasan a su representacion numerica, y los no digitos quedan "fuera de rango" en cierto sentido.

Entonces en tu codigo tienes que hacer el cambio aqui:

```cpp
        for (int i = 0; i < line.size() + 1; i++) {
            if (isdigit(line[i])) {
                num.push_back(line[i]);
            } else if ((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'e')) {
                letras.push_back(line[i]);
            }
        }
```

Cambiando el `num.push_back(line[i]);` por un `num.push_back(line[i] - '0');`